# Oracle Query Optimization for Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, oracle

Following query is taking too long (30 seconds). 
I think bottleneck is in where clause. Is it possible to optimize ?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS IN_HELP
FROM
    HCM.TableA
INNER JOIN
    HCM.EMPLOYEE_POSITION_BOX EPB
ON
    TableA.POSITION_BOX_CODE = EPB.POSITION_BOX_CODE AND NVL (V_DATE,SYSDATE) BETWEEN EPB.EFFECTIVE_DATE AND EPB.END_DATE
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    HCM.NODE_LEVEL_MASTER NLM
ON
    HCM.F_EMPLOYEE_ACTUAL_NODE(EPB.EMPLOYEE_CODE,TRUNC(SYSDATE)) = NLM.NODE_NO
LEFT JOIN
    HCM.POSITION_STATUS_MASTER PSM
ON
    TableA.STATUS = PSM.POSITION_STATUS_NO
WHERE
    NLM.NODE_NO_LEVEL2 = V_LOOP.NODE_NO_LEVEL2
    AND HCM.F_EMPLOYEE_ACTUAL_NODE(EPB.EMPLOYEE_CODE,TRUNC (SYSDATE)) <> TableA.NODE_NO
    AND PSM.FLAG = 'Y'
    AND TableA.STATUS <> '0108'
```

Comment: Do you really want e.g. PSM.FLAG = 'Y' in the WHERE clause? It makes the LEFT JOINs behave like regular INNER JOINs. Move the outer tables' conditions to the ON clauses instead if you really want LEFT JOINs!

Comment: First tool for optimisation = explain plan. Please provide an explain plan (as text, not image) in a fashion that can be clearly read.

Comment: Normally, First tool for optimisation = explain plan. BUT here we have no knowledge of that function. What does it do? This is probably most of the problem. There are other issues as well such as the alias V_LOOP. Is the query complete?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check the indexes for your tables from `WHERE` clause:

- NLM.NODE_NO_LEVEL2
- V_LOOP.NODE_NO_LEVEL2
- TableA.NODE_NO
- TableA.STATUS

`PSM.FLAG` shouldn't be added to the index as it will not provide some efficient filtering the data in tables.

Also, am I right that `HCM.F_EMPLOYEE_ACTUAL_NODE` is a function? If so, then you should consider to remove it from `WHERE` clause, as the execution plan won't examine the inside query, and it doesn't being optimized at all, which lead to performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is your function HCM.F_EMPLOYEE_ACTUAL_NODE. first move the function call to a subquery (epbx):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS IN_HELP
FROM
    HCM.TableA
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT HCM.F_EMPLOYEE_ACTUAL_NODE(EPB.EMPLOYEE_CODE,TRUNC(SYSDATE)) node, epb.* from HCM.EMPLOYEE_POSITION_BOX EPB) epbx
ON
    TableA.POSITION_BOX_CODE = EPBx.POSITION_BOX_CODE AND NVL (V_DATE,SYSDATE) BETWEEN EPBx.EFFECTIVE_DATE AND EPBx.END_DATE
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    HCM.NODE_LEVEL_MASTER NLM
ON
    epbx.node = NLM.NODE_NO
LEFT JOIN
    HCM.POSITION_STATUS_MASTER PSM
ON
    TableA.STATUS = PSM.POSITION_STATUS_NO
WHERE
    NLM.NODE_NO_LEVEL2 = V_LOOP.NODE_NO_LEVEL2
    AND epbx.node <> TableA.NODE_NO
    AND PSM.FLAG = 'Y'
    AND TableA.STATUS <> '0108'
```

Then use explain plan to find out whether your query is written efficiently.

Comment: Thanks. I have removed the function and use as above. now query runs in 1.7 seconds!